# Converting separate columns for mm, dd, and yr into a workable mm/dd/year format

Tags: sql

Basically I have 3 separate columns in a table. I will call them `SMonth`, `Sday`, `Syear`. They are stored as numeric values for some reason. I can use the following string to format them into what looks like a date but doesn't allow me to use functions such as sort, order by, datediff or dateadd.

```
CAST(SMonth AS varchar(2)) + '/' + CAST(SDay varchar(2)) + '/' + CAST(SYear AS varchar(4))
```

Anyone know how to convert this into a workable date, without changing the table?

It doesn't matter how it looks as long as I can use it ie a `date` or `datetime` makes no difference.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: looks like MS SQL which uses + sign to concat... I removed mysql based answer DOH!

Answer (score 2):

Just convert your result into a date or datetime.

```
DECLARE @SMonth AS INT = 12
DECLARE @SDay AS INT = 31
DECLARE @SYear as INT = 2013
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,CAST(@SMonth AS varchar(2)) + '/' + CAST(@SDay AS varchar(2)) + '/' + CAST(@SYear AS varchar(4)))
```

Comment: Using `+` sign to concatenate strings?

Answer (score 0):

you should convert format the string as `yyyy/mm/dd` in order to make sure that `SQL Server` uses `ODBC canonical` format

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar, Syear) + '/' + convert(VARCHAR, SMonth) + '/' + convert(VARCHAR, SDay ) )
```

Otherwise it your results could depend on the default `dateformat` or someone changed it using `SET DATEFORMAT`, for example:

`05/10/2013` could mean

- May 10, 2013 if the `DATEFORMAT` is `U.S`.
- October 5, 2013 if the `DATEFORMAT` is `Brithish / French`

see [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for complete reference of `dateformat`

Comment: Tried this. Got this result.

Comment: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: what are the values SMonth, SDay, SYear values you are dealing with? 
You can check my response using example: `;WITH a AS (SELECT CONVERT(varchar, 2003) + '/' + convert(VARCHAR, 5) + '/' + convert(VARCHAR, 10 )  AS StringType)
      SELECT StringType, CONVERT(DATETIME, StringType) AS DateType, 
        MONTH(CONVERT(DATETIME, StringType) ) MonthPart, 
        DAY(CONVERT(DATETIME, StringType) ) DayPart, 
        YEAR(CONVERT(DATETIME, StringType) ) YearPart
      FROM a`